# Should words in buttons or titles start with a capital?

Tags: buttons, wording, title, capitalization

I am currently in the process of creating an iOS application, and I was wondering about capitalization of buttons and titles.

For example, should a button say **"Add Post"** or **"Add post"**.

If I look at ux.stackexchange for example, I see buttons with the form "Ask Question" and "log in".

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55586/my-english-translator-capitalizes-every-noun-is-it-correct/55595#55595

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that's a preference thing.  The main thing is to be ***consistent*** with what you decide.

It could vary on what section of the app you are talking about too.  For example, your buttons and titles might be [Title Case](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/capitalstitle.htm) capitalized, while your links might be lowercase.

Again, just be consistent within the sections that you are standardizing.

Comment: https://twitter.com/jamesthomson/status/395364837456625664

Comment: @CharlesWesley - LoL ... they didn't subscribe to the consistency rule did they?

Comment: The reason Apple iOS uses a lowercase s for space is because it's not a function button or a call to action, it's a character on the keyboard. The buttons which appear to the right - cancel, search etc - are all functional and so Capitalised.

Answer (score 5):

The CTA *"Add post"* is in itself a sentence. The word *post* is (I'm assuming) not a product name but rather a word like any other word in a sentence and should be treated as such. Using the Title Case should be limited to writing titles, for CTA's (Call To Action) (<-Look, Title Case), you should use Sentence case because [that lowers the cognitive load of reading the text](http://www.sitepoint.com/typography-readability-legibility-part-2/).

However, assume that this was a different scenario. And you wanted to know about how to format a label saying *"my posts* which linked the user to an overview of all her posts. This label is a Title and not a CTA (Since the label doesn't start with a verb). Here it's OK to use the Title Case because it's a practiced convention. Using a Title Case in mere sentences, which also happens to be a CTA labels, is violating the conventional formatting style.

Answer (score 3):

The label in a button is considered a caption. Thus, style guides have it these need to be capitalised.

Oddly, a few style guides recommend the use of *Sentence case* rather than *Caption Case* for captions. See [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/48620/16924) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Apple as a guideline for that: [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/TextStyle/TextStyle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000365-BABDIBBH)

So if you're developing for iOS you probably should read it.

Answer (score 0):

**Character casing your call to action** – People generally don’t pay much attention to use proper casing on their button. However, text capitalization makes a noticeable difference in the conversion rate. When your call to action is small like one or two words, like **“Sign In”** or **“Buy Now”**, you can use the title case. Since the action word is only one or two words, it needs to be of a commanding nature, and hence the need to use title case on both words. But when you have a call to action that is more than that three to five words, using the ***sentence case*** makes the button feel more like a dialogue. All of this serves to make clicking a button more comfortable to the user.

More info - http://www.importux.com/intuitive-button-design-best-practices-guide/

Answer (score -1):

From a readability stand point i think **Add Post** is at a glance more recognizable than **Add post** or **add post**.

Avoid **ALL CAPS** as caps tend to be much more uniform in there width and height character to character making them much harder to read at a glance, where as when you have a mixture you can skim read the word allot easier - this article may also be interesting - http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/nation/2010-10-21-road-signs-all-caps-lowercase_N.htm